# install4j: compilation failed. Reason: java.io.IOException: com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel.build(L) contains a bytecode 00039

Tags: java, jenkins, install4j

**[install4j] WARNING: Error on output: java.io.IOException: com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel.build(L) contains a bytecode 00039: invokeinterface InterfaceMethodref:83 Con:256 with an unsupported constant reference; please use the pass-file option on this class.**

I have started getting this error suddenly while running the installer build. I have not changed any configurations.

I am unable to figure out the root cause for this issue. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a message from Pack200, which may not be able to pack all JAR files. Maybe you have changed the JRE version. You can switch off Pack200 compression on the "General Settings->Media file" options. Alternatively, if the JAR file has the name `codemodel.jar`, you can create an empty file `codemodel.jar.nopack` to disable Pack200 compression just for that JAR file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingo Kegel. I disabled the compression and the build is back to normal. However, the build size has increased. I think option-2 mentioned above will fix this (i.e. Disabling compression at a jar level instead of globally disabling compression) 

W.r.t option-2, can you explain where should I place the "codemodel.jar.nopack" file?

Comment: In the same directory as the `codemode.jar` file. It has to have the exact same name with `.nopack` appended.